# LINQ to SQL Check if DB is Down and Log Why

Tags: c#, linq

In my application I want to be able to check to see if the connection to the database failed. If so, I need to know about it immediately. I could just do a try/catch around the first query that is run using LINQ, but I feel there must be a better way. Let's say I have the following chunk of code:

```
        if (db.DatabaseExists())
        {
             //Do work
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.Error("DB DOWN");
        }
```

That works and is cleaner, but I have no way of logging WHY the database is down. Knowing LINQ there very well could be some helper function I don't know about that can give me the reason it can't connect without throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DataContext.Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.connection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, Try to open it , if you get an exception then Log the exception, that will give you some information. `DataContext.DatabaseExists` returns true/false but no other information. You can do it like:

```
try
{
     //Check if it is not already open
     DataContext.Connection.Open();
}
catch (SqlException sEx)
{
    //Log sEx
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // log ex
}
finally
{
    if (DataContext.Connection != null && DataContext.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        DataContext.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```